# EnumWindows enumeration problem (hidden window?)

Tags: c++, windows, list, winapi

Im facing a problem with enumwindows - it actually doesn't find all windows.
Example

[image]

processhacker lists more windows with this classname, any solution to actually list all windows?

```cpp
BOOL CALLBACK enumWindowCallback(HWND hWnd, LPARAM lparam) {
    int length = 22;
    char* buffer = new char[length + 1];
    GetClassNameA(hWnd, buffer, length + 1);
    std::string windowTitle(buffer);

    if (strcmp(buffer, "ApplicationFrameWindow") == 0) {
        std::cout << hWnd << ":  " << windowTitle << std::endl;
    }
    return TRUE;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << "Enmumeration" << std::endl;
    EnumWindows(enumWindowCallback, NULL);
    std::cin.ignore();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: Are you sure those are windows and not processes?

Comment: probably you have not [disableWindowFiltering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sbscs/application-manifests#disableWindowFiltering) in manifest

Comment: microsoft spy++ can easily show these windows so they are windows for sure

Comment: @ZUCZEKUINS `EnumWindows()` enumerates only top-level windows. Are those other windows top-level? Also, you didn't say which version of Windows you are using. `ApplicationFrameWindow` is typically used only for Store apps, but in Win8+ `EnumWindows()` only enumerates windows of Desktop apps. Also, your callback is leaking the `new[]`'ed memory, and wasting overhead on a useless `std::string`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau i could find the window with findwindowex, thanks for help